# How to fail and throw exceptions when a rule can't be fully matched , in PetitParserDart?

Tags: parsing, petitparser

I have defined some rules with [PetitParserDart](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart):

```
def("start", ref("rule").separatedBy(char('\n'), includeSeparators: false);
def("rule", char('(').seq(word().plus()).seq(char(')')));
```

So the following text will be matched:

```
(aaa)
(bbbbbb)
```

But if there are some lines can't match:

```
(aaaa)
bbbbb
(cccccccc
```

How to define the grammars to let it fail and throw exceptions on line `(ccccccccc`, but not on line `bbbbb`?

I mean it only throw exceptions when a rule is not fully matched. If nothing matchs, it won't throw exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any point in the grammar you can introduce a failing parser:

```dart
failure('This parser always fails at this point');
```

Normally PetitParser does not use exceptions during parsing, success and failure are indicated with the respective `Success` and `Failure` response contexts.

That said, it is possible to throw exceptions, but normally not advised unless the user of your grammar can deal with it. For example, you could define a throwing parser factory like this:

```dart
Parser thrower(String message) {
  return epsilon().map((value) => throw new IllegalStateException(message));
}
```

Using the normal compositors you can then generate very precise error messages:

```dart
char('(')
  .seq(word().plus())
  .seq(char(')')
    // causes the parser to continue trying to parse the input
    .or(failure('something bad happened')))
```

Or with the helper above:

```dart
char('(')
  .seq(word().plus())
  .seq(char(')')
     // stops parsing altogether and throws an exception
    .or(thrower('something bad happened')))
```